# Comparing a .getAtributte("value") in while loop

Tags: javascript, selenium, loops

[image]

[image]

I have this element in a web page which i trying to automate, my problem is i have created a function to clear the input or texts slots pressing the backspace key until the element length become 0, but i am trying to make another condition to be the element be equal to "0,00". I've tryed witch the bellow code:

```
async clear(locator) {

    await this.locate(locator)
    
    let aux = await element.getAttribute("value");
    
    console.log("Value to be cleaned: ",aux)
    while (aux.length > 0 || aux != "0,00") {
        await element.sendKeys(Key.BACK_SPACE);
        aux = await element.getAttribute("value");
        
        console.log('A|',aux,'|',typeof aux)
        console.log('B|',"0,00","|",typeof "0,00")
    }

}
```

The problem is it results in an infinite loop despite the parameters appears to be the same i've put the console log's to compare and i've received the following output:

[image]

The results look to be the same but the condition never is fulfilled and enters in the infinite loop.

Comment: I think `async clear(locator) {` is a syntax error?

Comment: How so? I use the locator to pass the xpath of the element i want to locate and clear.

Comment: Doesn’t it need the keyword “function”?

Comment: Ah it's in a class. Then the keyword is not needed

Comment: yes exactly I had forgotten it myself lol

Answer (score 0):

You have to write while loop like this:

```
while (aux.length > 0 && aux != "0,00") {
    await element.sendKeys(Key.BACK_SPACE);
    aux = await element.getAttribute("value");
    
    console.log('A|',aux,'|',typeof aux)
    console.log('B|',"0,00","|",typeof "0,00")
}
```

You wrongly placed || (Or) instead of && (And).

Comment: But I want it to stop the loop when any of the conditions are fulfilled, even if one of them its not.

Comment: Did you try using &&? This should solve your problem.  This loop will be continued if aux.length is bigger than 0 AND aux is not 0,00. So, either your input will become 0,00 or its length will become 0. In each one of the conditions that you mentioned, while loop will stop/get broken. Is there any other condition?